# Asp Core 2.1 Jwt + Identity. userManager store does not implement IUserRoleStore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-identity

I am trying to work with Jwt auth and Identity in ASP Net Core 2.1

In my Startup.cs I have:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = AuthOptions.ISSUER,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = AuthOptions.AUDIENCE,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = AuthOptions.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(),
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        };
    });

var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<User>(options =>
{
    // Password settings
    ...
    // Lockout settings
    ...
    // User settings
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(IdentityRole), builder.Services);

Then in SecurityService.cs I am trying to get roles by using this statement

```
var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
```

And its throwing the following exception:

> NotSupportedException: Store does not implement IUserRoleStore
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager.GetUserRoleStore()

I found it because of `AddIdentityCore`: If I use 
`AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>` instead it works, but then `[Authorize]` doesn't work

Does anybody faced similar situation, or why it can happen?

Comment: `AddIdentityCore` doesn't register the role-related stuff, so that makes sense. When you say *[Authorize] doesn't work*, what does that mean, specifically?

Comment: @KirkLarkin with AddIdentityCore it gives me access to endpoint, but without I am getting redirection to login page

Comment: Just to confirm - that endpoint is using JWT authentication?

Comment: @KirkLarkin yes, I am setting this in startup.cs - AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>`, that call configures the default authentication scheme, like so ([source](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/release/2.1/src/Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L45)):

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
})
```

In your `Startup.ConfigureServices`, you have the following, which *also* sets the default authentication scheme:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
```

Because of the order this is defined (`AddIdentity` is *after* `AddAuthentication`), the default is changing from Jwt to Identity, so that when you use `[Authorize]`, the authentication process is now expecting to use Identity rather than Jwt.

To resolve this, the simplest option is to switch the order of `AddIdentity` and `AddAuthentication`, so the JwtBearer call comes last and therefore "wins". You'll also need to be more explicit and set both `DefaultAuthenticateScheme` and `DefaultChallengeScheme`:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(...);
```

Another option is to be explicit in the `[Authorize]` attribute, calling out *which* authentication scheme you want to use, like either of the following two lines:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)]
```

It seems the first option would be most appropriate for your use-case, but it's good to know that this second option exists should you need it as you go further with Identity (there are more - e.g. using policies).