# Tokens based security using AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server stops working after adding identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, openid-connect

I've created a small .NET Core website which allows the user to get a bearer token using AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server. It works as expected until I add `services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>();`

After adding identity the log doesn't show any signs of token validation and `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is always `false`. Tokens are still generated - only the validation seems to be skipped.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddAuthentication(OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddOAuthValidation(OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddOpenIdConnectServer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenEndpointPath = "/token";
            options.AllowInsecureHttp = true;
            options.ApplicationCanDisplayErrors = true;

            options.Provider.OnValidateTokenRequest = context =>
            {
                context.Validate();

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };

            options.Provider.OnHandleTokenRequest = context =>
            {
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Scheme.Name,
                    OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name,
                    OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role);

                identity.AddClaim(OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject, "[unique id]");

                var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                                    new ClaimsPrincipal(identity),
                                    new AuthenticationProperties(),
                                    context.Scheme.Name);

                context.Validate(ticket);

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        });

    // When the following line is uncommented the bearer token isn't validated anymore
    //services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>();

    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

An example controller actions could be this:

```
public bool Get() => HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
```

and if I add the `Authorize` attribute I'll receive a 404:

```
[Authorize]
public bool Get() => HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
```

To create a token I do something like this:

```
POST http://localhost:5005/token HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:5005
Content-Length: 69
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=web&grant_type=password&username=username&password=password
```

And the request with the bearer token looks like this:

```
GET http://localhost:5005/customer HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:5005
Authorization: Bearer <the token received in the previous call>
```

The entire program can be downloaded here:
https://gist.github.com/nielslbeck/e454cc1b79aa56948c96f4a24438b34e

Comment: My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52207398/2630078) should help resolve this.

Comment: If you're getting a 404 after adding the authorize attribute to the method, then probably the request is being redirected to a route that isn't implemented in the authorization server. I experienced something similar with IdentityServer4 and the `/oidc/sign-in` route (or something similar). Is the `/token` path implemented? Sorry, what I mean to say is, try setting the token endpoint to `/connect/token` since maybe that is what is implemented by default.

Comment: @BlackyWolf Yes, it’ll be redirecting to `/Account/Login` due to that call to `AddDefaultIdentity`.