# Why my OAuth provider works incorrectly when I add Identity to a project?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have code that authenticates an user using OAuth. Here is this code: [Github link](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/tree/dev/src/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Vkontakte)
I use this code in the `ConfigureServices()` method of the Startup class:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{     
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options=>
        {
            options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
            options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/Logout");
            options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Forbidden");
        })
        .AddVkontakte(options =>    // here
        {
            options.ApiVersion = "5.95";
            options.ClientId = Configuration["VKontakte:ClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["VKontakte:ClientSecret"];
        });

    services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>(options =>
    {
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

But when I try to authenticate using it, nothing happens. It works the way I want, only when I remove this strokes

```cs
...
services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>(options =>
{
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

---

In both cases, the code behind `.AddVkontakte(...)` works correctly, I checked it in the network inspector of the browser. My code makes requests to the OAuth provider(vk.com) and successfully gets responses.  But I don't understand why `AddDefaultIdentity<User>(...)` doesn't allow `.AddVkontakte(...)` to authenticate an user.

What do you think about this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I looked at this question ([Asp Core 2.1 Jwt + Identity. userManager store does not implement IUserRoleStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52206742/asp-core-2-1-jwt-identity-usermanager-store-does-not-implement-iuserrolestore/52207398)), and tried to change a little bit options passed to `AddAuthentication`, and it worked!

Here is the final code:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{     
    services.AddAuthentication(options=>   // defined some options
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie(options=>
        {
            options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
            options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/Logout");
            options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Forbidden");
        })
        .AddVkontakte(options =>
        {
            options.ApiVersion = "5.95";
            options.ClientId = Configuration["VKontakte:ClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["VKontakte:ClientSecret"];
        });

    services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>(options =>
    {
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

---

I don't know what does it mean, but it works! Wait and see.