# services.AddIdentity causes my controller's endpoint to respond with 404

Tags: asp.net-core, identity

I'm having some difficulty that I can't figure out in regards to adding a new Bearer authentication to my application, a piece of code I require is causing my endpoint to return a 404 error, yet when removed I am successfully able to reach the endpoint without the 404 error, see below.

Firstly, my application acts as both an Identity Server and also as an API which accepts Bearer tokens.

```
        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://www.example.com/";
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("ApiScope", policy =>
            {
                policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                policy.RequireClaim("scope", "openid");
            });
        });

        // THIS IS THE CODE CAUSING THE 404 ERROR
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DevContext>();
```

From the above, if I try to reach my controller's endpoint which makes use of the [Authorize] decoration, then I am presented with a 404 response. If I comment out the last couple of lines (see comment within the code), then I am successfully able to reach my endpoint.

Why would I be getting a 404 error? I assume it must be because the .AddIdentity is overwriting the Bearer authentication and because my controller is decorated with [Authorize] I'm unable to reach it?

Is it not possible to have my application as both an API and also an Identity Server?

---

This is what I see within the Output logs when the problematic code is uncommented (404 response):

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44310/api
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization failed.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was challenged.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished in 13.422ms 302 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44310/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished in 2.0776ms 404
```

This is what I see when the problematic code is commented (successful response):

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44310/api
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler: Information: Successfully validated the token.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization was successful.
```

Comment: Put your call to `AddIdentity` above the call to `AddAuthentication` and it should work.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Unfortunately it doesn't seem to make a difference - I still receive the 404 error even when the AddAuthentication is below the call to AddIdentity. I added some output logs to my original post above, hoping these might be able to make more sense of what's going on?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52207398/2630078, where I explain what's happening here and how to fix it.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Thank you! That was exactly what I needed. I have been on this all day, thank you so so much!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I marked this as a duplicate so it's linked to the answer that helped you out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comments by Kirk Larkin helped resolved this, to summarise:

1. `AddIdentity` had to be placed above the call to `AddAuthentication`
2. My controller had to be decorated with `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`